# Simplify JS so hash isn't needed hard coded in the script

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash

I'm trying to find a way to simplify this script so that it doesn't need the hash names hard coded. So if you add a new link with the hash mytest and a div with the ID mytest it will work without having to visit the script and add mytest into the script. Hope I'm making my question clear.

My very kind thanks for any help figuring this out.

```
            jQuery(function($) {
              $('#menu-bottomnav li a').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                animateSlider(this.hash);
              });

              function animateSlider(hash) {
                if (!$('#popups div.open').length) {
                  if (hash == '#bio') {
                    openPopup(hash);
                  }
                  if (hash == '#resume') {
                    openPopup(hash);
                  }
                } else {
                  if (hash == '#bio') {
                    openAndClose(hash)
                  }
                  if (hash == '#resume') {
                    openAndClose(hash)
                  }
                }
              }


              function openPopup(hash) {
                $(hash).slideToggle().addClass('open');
              }


              function openAndClose(hash) {
                if ($(hash).hasClass('open')) {
                  $($(hash)).slideToggle().removeClass('open');
                } else {
                  $('#popups div.open').slideToggle().removeClass('open');
                  $(hash).slideToggle().addClass('open');
                }
              }
            });
```

Have a working example here https://jsfiddle.net/a4y7z2fm/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#menu-bottomnav li a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    animateSlider(this.hash);
  });

  function animateSlider(hash) {
    $('.open').slideToggle().removeClass('open');
    $(hash).slideToggle().addClass('open');
  }
});
```

Comment: better than my answer ;)

Comment: Heh, thanks! :)   -- Man, I keep on using this site like its reddit.

Comment: Perfect exactly what I was looking to for!

Comment: Awesome, I'm happy I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I don't understand the question, but it seems like it'd work just fine if you just passed the hash variable without the if statements at all:

```
jQuery(function($) {
$('#menu-bottomnav li a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    animateSlider(this.hash);
});

function animateSlider(hash) {
    if (!$('#popups div.open').length) {
        openPopup(hash);
    } else {
        openAndClose(hash);
    }
 }


 function openPopup(hash) {
     $(hash).slideToggle().addClass('open');
 }


function openAndClose(hash) {
    if ($(hash).hasClass('open')) {
        $($(hash)).slideToggle().removeClass('open');
    } else {
        $('#popups div.open').slideToggle().removeClass('open');
        $(hash).slideToggle().addClass('open');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: brilliant I've been on this for so many hours I was overlooking the simple answer quack thought of. But I have to give it to hola you hit the nail on the head I really wanted to simplify my horrible code. I'm not the best I mostly know how to make a functional mess Thank you both!!!!